# How could I shutdown a remote host, in my network thru ssh, with a local host?

Tags: ssh, shutdown, openssh, wakeonlan

The question is simple.
What would be the script I would have to use to shut down a computer in my network thru ssh.

Normaly i would go to command line and:

```
ssh desktop

delik@desktop's password: 

delik@desktop:~$ sudo shutdown -P 0
```

To power on I created a file and wrote:

```
wakeonlan xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

And gave it the executable bit

That way to power on it requires only a double click. Would i be capable of doing the same to shutdown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the following I am assuming that the user you are going to use in `remote-host` is the same you use in `local-host`.

In order to do what you want, you have to first authorize your `local-host` to connect to you `remote-host` with no password. To do that you have to ([as described here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)):

1. Install `ssh`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ssh
   ```
2. Create public and private keys using `ssh-key-gen` on `local-host` by entering this command in your `localhost`:

   ```
   ssh-keygen
   ```

   You should save the generated key in:

   ```
   /home/yourusername/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

   Press enter twice to leave the passphrase empty.

   ```
   Your identification has been saved in /home/yourusername/.ssh/id_rsa.
   Your public key has been saved in /home/yourusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
   The key fingerprint is:
   XX:XX:XX:xX:XX:xX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX yourusername@local-host
   ```
3. Copy the public key to the `remote-host` using `ssh-copy-id`:

   ```
   yourusername@local-host$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
   yourusername@remote-host's password:

   Now try logging into the machine, with:

   ssh remote-host
   ```

   and check in `.ssh/authorized_keys` to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

   Note: `ssh-copy-id` appends the keys to the `remote-host`’s `/home/yourusername/.ssh/authorized_key`.
4. Login to `remote-host` without entering the password:

   ```
   ssh remote-host
   yourusername@remote-host:~$
   ```

   **Access to `remote-host` with no password. Success!**

Now you have to be able to [execute `sudo shutdown -P 0` with no password](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/315/how-to-shutdown-and-reboot-without-sudo-password/). You can do that by modifying `/etc/sudoers` on `remote-host` with `visudo`. That way, user `yourusername` can execute the `shutdown` command with no password asked.

1. Login to the `remote-host`:

   ```
   ssh remote.host
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```

   By running `visudo`, you edit `/etc/sudoers` in a safe manner.
3. Add this line to the file:

   ```
   yourusername ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
   ```
4. After doing that, get back to your `local-host`, create a new empty file and paste this line, modifying the `remote-host`'s name:

   ```
   ssh remote.host sudo shutdown -P 0
   ```
5. Save and close the file, <kbd>right-click</kbd> on it to go to its *Properties* → *Permissions*, and tick *Execute this file as a program*.

Script done!

Comment: Thanks [mene](http://askubuntu.com/users/91832/mene) for your head's up :)

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For me on my 18.04 server, the keygen and `sudoers` edits did not work on their own. Finally, after a big hassle, I managed to remote shutdown my server with the following command:

```
plink -batch -ssh -P 222 -t user@server -pw XXX "sudo -S shutdown"
```

I edited `sudoers` so that:

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an user-account with a keyfile instead of a password (so you don't have to type in the password to login).
You can also give the user a "default shell" that is not bash or sh, but "shutmedown.sh" or something like this, which will exec your shutdown-code.

Comment: Would you improve your answer with some examples on how to do that exactly?

Comment: You can check this out for the login part: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/
You can use   usermod -s /home/username/myscript.sh username  to change the default shell.
The script should be something like  
#!/bin/bash
shutdown -P now

Comment: You are right, the ssh login problem is solved, but now I have to build a script with a "pause" so it waits for `ssh desktop` to happen succesfully. And after that i have another problem how to give the command in `sudo` and enter the password?

Comment: I manage to do that. Now I can shut down with sudo shutdown -P 0 with no password

Comment: you can pause a script with the "sleep" command. "sleep 10" for 10 seconds.

Comment: I already have the full condensed answer but i'm unable to post it here... need 10 rep..

Comment: @mene, would you consider editing your answer to add the details you posted as comments? That way, your answer will be clear, complete and useful to other users.